# what type of insect is this? is this a moth? (southeast asia - Malaysia)

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

i found this insect in the garden behind my house a few months ago.This is the first time i saw this insect.On that day the weather is very hot.I found the insect in the afternoon.I am from Kelantan,Malaysia.The climate in Malaysia is equatorial, hot and humid, heavy rain falls in the monsoon season between november and february.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Oleander Hawkmoth (Daphnis nerii)

Same fellow? (From [oocities.org](http://www.oocities.org/rainforest/Vines/8983/moths/oleander.html))

[image]

And a better picture from [ukmoths.org.uk](https://ukmoths.org.uk/species/daphnis-nerii/adult/#prettyPhoto):

[image]

For more reading, [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphnis_nerii) a wiki article.